# Преобразовать строку в метод

Tags: python, математика

Существует строка, например `operation = "sin"` нужно эту строку использовать в модуле `math` как метод, то есть `math.operation(2)`.

Вряд ли код ниже похож на попытку моего решения, однако думаю он разъяснит мои намерения.

```
import math


operation = 'sin'
print(math.operation(2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `match-case`:

```
import math

op = 'sin'

match op:
    case 'sin':
        print(math.sin(2))
    case 'cos':
        print(math.cos(2))
```

Можно сделать так:

```
import math

op = 'sin'

print(getattr(math, op)(2))
```

Можно использовать `eval` (но это ОЧЕНЬ НЕ рекомендуется из соображений безопасности):

```
import math

op = 'sin'

print(eval(f'math.{op}(2)'))
```

Comment: Через `getattr` по идее самый правильный метод - и лишнего описывать не нужно и безопасно довольно.

Answer (score 1):

еще как вариант:

```
operations = math.__dict__
operations['sin'](2)  # 0.9092974268256817
```